# Assistance with HTML5 Canvas and JS displaying images on it please?

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-canvas

I'm making an Android game, in HTML5 and Javascript, I am part of the way there, but have hit something that has stumped me, My JS file and my Html file were working together, to draw on the canvas etc, but now I'm trying to draw an image on the canvas, nothing is being displayed, I know the `img` function is being found, as, `alert (img);`, works so it's just lost on me. (currently this is copied from a book I was given at college, and it's identical, the JS has been verified in JSHint and passes, so I'm lost) also, please be quite simple, I'm pretty new to JS but have used html for a long time, and this just has to be a simple game for a college assignment.

My HTML code is

```
<canvas id="game" width="1024" height="600">Sorry, your browser does not support this</canvas>
```

and my JS is:

```
function init() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('game');
    var canvas = elem.getContext('2d');
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.minkbooks.com/content/snow.jpg');
    img.addEventListener("load", function() {
        canvas.drawImage(img, 20, 20);
        alert(canvas);
    });
}   
addEventListener("load", init);
```

and here it is on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xw8m7/

Comment: Just FYI, in your jsfiddle, change the dropdown on the left from "onload" to "onDOMready".  That allows the page to finish loading, and I am seeing the image load.

Comment: yes thankyou, that works, but how would i implement that into my JS file now please?

Comment: To make your question more useful to the community, I'd recommend that you edit it.  Your issue appears to be a question of running your code using XDK.  There is a tag for that, intel-xdk.  If not that, then it has to do with targeting the correct event in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on your jsfiddle.  You are executing your javascript code as soon as it is loaded.  Depending on where your code is located in the html, the canvas element might not be loaded yet, and that would prevent your code from loading the image into the canvas element, and you would still get the alert.

In JSFiddle, you need to set the option of running your code "onDomready".  That means that the JavaScript won't run until everything has been loaded (your canvas element).  After changing that in your jsfiddle, your function loaded the image into the canvas just fine.

**Update:**
Based on your comment about XDK, I found a bit of example code and modified it.  Original source:  https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493117

```
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",function(){
    init();        
},false);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, in jsfiddle, the ondomready thing works perfectly, so how would i implement that into my code in XDK please?

Comment: You'll need to do some research.  I have not used the XDK.  For the web, you would use something like this:  window.onload(function(){ init(); });
See if this link is useful:  https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/493117